# connection errors in the grinder

Tags: java, load-testing, grinder

I am trying to use [the grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) load testing tool to reproduce the navigation recorded on a `.har` file using chrome dev tools.

I have generated [this test script](http://pastebin.com/fxbBz6JP) using [har2grinder](https://github.com/postrational/har2grinder/).

The script looks faily simple, just a bunch of get/post invocations and their headers.

I launch the grinder console:

`java -classpath lib/grinder.jar net.grinder.Console`

And then the agent processes, using [this properties file](http://pastebin.com/xbSB5e3h):

`java -classpath lib/grinder.jar net.grinder.Grinder grinder.properties`

Then I start the whole thing from the console and all I can get is this output, showing 1000 errors on each of the 2 pages visited:

[image]

The web server (tomcat) log doesn't show any hits, and I don't see any grinder logs with any further details. How can I trace the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant access the properties file :(

You need to look into the properties first and get the logs working , 
Please check **grinder.logDirectory** value , the logs will contain information .

Secondly check whether **grinder.useConsole** is set or not and the value of grinder.consolePort grinder.consoleHost have been edited to something other than default .Usually this change is not required.

Also set **grinder.processes ,grinder.thread** and **grinder.run** to 1 so that there is only one process with one thread and executes once will be easier to debug .

Next if you are NOT running against localhost then probably check that its not getting blocked across firewall since Grinder is really fast and can send many request in a small time .However these type of errors will get recorded in grinder logs and are very self explanatory.